# How to Change Default System Wide UMASK on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

The default umask on 18.04 LTS is 0022.

I want to set it to 0027 system wide. So for example when logrotate renames old log files, it respects the 0027 umask.

There are no logins on the system only ssh. So this is not a question that can be solved by editing /etc/login.defs
Ideas?

Googled this for hours and haven't found a reliable answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a line to `/etc/pam.d/common-session` reading

```
session optional pam_umask.so
```

or it may already be enabled. Then edit `/etc/login.defs` and change the UMASK line to

> UMASK           002

(the default is 022).

Comment: My users do not login under pam. They only use ssh.
Also UsePAM = no in sshd. So this solution won't work. There must be another place to set umask...

Comment: Looks like ext4 file system does not allow mask options in /etc/fstab. I think the only answer is to write recursive ACLs on the mount paths.